# sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score returns mean_absolute_percentage_error regardless what I choose in the estimator

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn

Please tell me if it's possible to change scoring for `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` ? It returns the negative value of the `mean_absolute_percentage_error` regardless of my choice in the estimator. For example if I select `metrics=['mean_absolute_error']` it would be changed during ANN training but `cross_val_score` will still return the negative value of the `mean_absolute_percentage`.

My code is:

```
def create_network():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='mse',
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
    return model


from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
neural_network = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_network, 
                                 epochs=20, 
                                 batch_size=10, 
                                 verbose=1)

X=feature_normalization(X)[0]

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(neural_network, X, y, cv=4)
print ('Scores:',scores)
print ('Average score:',np.average(scores))
```

Results:

```
Epoch 20/20
380/380 [==============================] - 0s 82us/step - loss: 18.5750 - mean_absolute_error: 2.9808
126/126 [==============================] - 0s 124us/step
Scores: [-27.60875144 -15.73322312 -35.57359647 -21.53566427]
Average score: -25.112808823950544
```

Comment: "*regardless of my choice in the estimator*" sounds like too general a statement that is not supported by what you show here, keeping in mind that the Keras wrapper which you use is a special case, as it's not a *native* sklearn estimator. Please update your post to clarify that you are specifically interested in getting the MAE using the Keras wrapper shown (or otherwise, if this is not the case).

Comment: I'm not specifically interested in MAE, I'm interested if I can get with the Keras wrapper something except MAPE and if it's possible how can I get it. Above is just an example of the code and it's results.

Comment: Don't have the time to look it in depth now, but - keeping in mind that, as I said, Keras wrapper is not a native sklearn estimator, there is a good chance that `cross_val_score` without explicitly specifying its `scoring` argument doesn't "know" exactly what to do here. So, your very first act should be to try by explicitly specifying a `scoring` argument.